# How to rewrite anonymous functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to programming and Python particularly Python3. Using an online tutorial I'm trying to understand the use of 'lambda'. Therefore, I would like to rewrite the following code and use other named functions, list comprehension, dict comprehension or generator. However struggle with the syntax. I'm not able to rewrite the `lambdas`.

Original function:

```
import functools as ft
import itertools as it
import os
import re
import requests
import tempfile
def foo(los, n=None):
    n = n or len(los)
    h = it.takewhile(lambda p: p[0] < n, enumerate(los))
    s = sorted(h, key=lambda p: p[1])
    g = it.groupby(s, lambda p: p[1])
    return dict(it.starmap(lambda k, vs: (k, sum(map(lambda i: 1, vs))), g))

alist=[1,2,3,1,1,7,8,9,9]

print(foo(alist))

{1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 2}
```

My adjustment:

```
def smaller_then_ten(e):
    return e[0] < len(e)

def foo(los, n=None):
    n = n or len(los)
    h = it.takewhile(smaller_then_n, enumerate(los))
    s = sorted(h)
    g = it.groupby(s)
    return dict(it.starmap(lambda k, vs: (k, sum(map(lambda i: 1, vs))), g))

alist=[1,2,3,1,1,7,8,9,9]

print(foo(alist))
```

Comment: In the words of Alex Trebek, "Your response must be in the form of a question."  What's wrong?

Comment: Hi Malvolio, my problem is that I just cant figure out how to rewrite the lambdas with different functions.

Comment: `h = it.takewhile(lambda e: e[0] < len(e), enumerate(los))`?

Comment: `smaller_than_ten`. *Probably* not the source of your problems, but still, heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite it like this...

For:

```
lambda args: expression_with_args
```

a function would look like:

```
def func_name(args):
    return expression_with_args
```

E.g.

```
lambda p: p[0] < n
```

becomes:

```
def compare_func(p, n):
    return p[0] < n
```

to use it as a function for `key`, which takes only one argument it has to be modified a little to save the value of `n`:

```
compare_func = ft.partial(compare_func, n=n)
```

E.g.

```
lambda p: p[1]
```

becomes:

```
def get_first(p):
    return p[1]
```

E.g.

```
lambda k, vs: (k, sum(map(lambda i: 1, vs)))
```

becomes:

```
def as_one(i):
    return 1

def get_tuple(k, vs):
    vs_with_ones = map(as_one, vs)
    vs_sum = sum(vs_with_ones)
    return (k, vs_sum)
```

Finally:

```
def foo(los, n=None):
    n = n or len(los)
    compare_func = ft.partial(compare_func, n=n)
    h = it.takewhile(compare_func, enumerate(los))
    s = sorted(h, key=get_first)
    g = it.groupby(s, get_first)
    return dict(it.starmap(get_tuple, g))
```

Comment: Hi Nikita, thank you for the suggestions! However, in get_tuple() there seems to be an error at least the code is not running. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @HiThere, please try again as I updated it several times. Also, note that `get_tuple()` depends on `as_one()`. I checked and it worked, e.g. for `get_tuple(123, (100, 200, 300, 400))` i get `(123, 4)`.

Comment: Thank you for your support Nikita! However, I still get `s = sorted(h, key = get_first)
TypeError: compare_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n' `

Comment: @HiThere, I just showed how to convert lambda to functions literally. But ofc, depending on applications some adjustments are required and the names could be better. In this particular case: single argument is given to a predicate function in `takewhile()`, so it doesn't get `n`; to solve this, one way is to create a partial with `n` being saved - please, see answer update.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is a simple typo. Your defined your "smaller than" function as `smaller_then_ten` but called it as `smaller_then_n`. I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that you meant to call it `smaller_than_len`. Next is that your function `smaller_then_ten` doesn't take your variable `n` into account at all, it only uses the length of the input list. What you really want is a function that accepts an upper bound and returns a function which checks the first element of the list against it. Something like this.

```
def smaller_than_len(n):
    def f(e):
        return e[0] < n
    return f

def foo(los, n=None):
    n = n or len(los)
    h = it.takewhile(smaller_than_len(n), enumerate(los))
    ...
```

Your final problem is that you removed the key argument from the `sorted` and `groupby` functions. Since you said that you didn't want to use lambdas for your adjustment, you can replace them with a new function named "key_func".

```
def smaller_than_len(n):
    def f(e):
        return e[0] < n
    return f

def key_func(e):
    return e[1]

def foo(los, n=None):
    n = n or len(los)
    h = it.takewhile(smaller_than_len(n), enumerate(los))
    s = sorted(h, key=key_func)
    g = it.groupby(s, key=key_func)
    return dict(it.starmap(lambda k, vs: (k, sum(map(lambda i: 1, vs))), g))
```

Now your function should work correctly.

Comment: Hi Kwarztz, thank you for your answer. Using your suggestion I get an empty set. But I think I get the idea.

Comment: @HiThere, yeah, I forgot to add the return statement at the end of `smaller_than_len`. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember is a function is defined (via `def` or `lambda`) in a certain environment or scope.  In your example function, the lambdas are defined inside of `foo()` and therefore have access to `foo`'s local variables (like `n`).  When `smaller_then_ten` is defined outside of `foo`, it doesn't have access to the variable `n`.  Kwarrtz and Nikita each showed ways to solve that issue.  However, the easiest way is to define the new function in the same environment that the lambdas where in, like so:

```
def foo(los, n=None):
    def smaller_than_n(tpl):
        return tpl[0] < n

    def item1(tpl):
        return tpl[1]

    def const1(i):
        return 1

    def count(key, values):
        return key, sum(map(const1, values))

    n = n or len(los)
    h = it.takewhile(smaller_than_n, enumerate(los))
    s = sorted(h, key=item1)
    g = it.groupby(s, key=item1)
    return dict(it.starmap(count, g))
```

As you are learning Python, get familiar with the standard library.  It is a great resource.  To pique your interest: the first two lines of `foo()` could be replaced by `itertools.islice`, `item1()` could be replaced by `operator.itemgetter`, and the whole `foo` function could be replaced by `collections.Counter`.